# Are mlr3 class weights applied to validation score calculations?

Tags: r, validation, classification, imbalanced-data, mlr3

I have previously used `mlr3` for imbalanced classification problems, and used `PipeOpClassWeights` to apply class weights to learners during training. This pipe op adds a column of observation weights to the `Task`, in the `Task$weights` property. These observation weights are then passed to the `Learner` during training.

Some classification performance metrics, such as Brier score (`classif.bbrier`) and log loss (`classif.logloss`) can be calculated with class weights applied (this is what happens to the training log loss when we train with class weights).

My question is, when we perform validation with `resample`, and aggregate performance metrics from the results, in the form of

```
resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 4)
measure = msr("classif.bbrier")
result = resample(task, learner, resampling)
score = resampling$aggregate(measure)
```

are the class weights applied to this validation score calculation too (if applicable to the particular measure)? Is this also done when we perform hyperparameter tuning, for example with `AutoTuner`?

I looked in the documentation for the aforementioned classes, and the resampling [section](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/performance.html#sec-resampling-exec) of mlr3book, but couldn't find an answer. I assume we'd want the same class weights applied to the training loss to be applied to the validation loss, at least for hyperparameter tuning if not for performance testing.

I was inspired to investigate this after coming across a similar issue in the validation scores of `xgboost`'s Python implementation, discussed [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/8184).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are. If they're not, that's a bug.